# In firebase cloud function how to get which app user is logged

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

We are creating user profile in firestore using cloud function
when new user create cloud function will trigger and we write the user info to firebase collection but, now in my firebase we have 2 apps and in need to store user profile in two different collection 
The issue is how can i identify which app is users by the user for login app A or app B
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Will your users share uids on the 2 collections or not? can't you use a flag when calling the cloud funtion to identify where it is coming from?

Comment: ok, that is a  good idea, but In my case cloud function will trigger when new auth created and it is done by firebase. So, here how can I add a flag?

Comment: can you share some code of you cloud function and how it is being called by the creation event?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send to the cloud function the tokenId of your user, you can [get the tokenID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken) doing something like this:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function (token) {
    // Send the token
})
```

Then, on the cloud function you need to [decode the tokenID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken) to get the [current userId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken#uid), you can do something like the following:

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(function(decodedToken) {
    var uid = decodedToken.uid;
})
```

With the uid, you can use `admin.auth().getUser(uid)` to get the current user record.